# Enable TLS in bareos client

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, bacula

I have a bareos client trying to communicate with aws s3 server.
As per http://doc.bareos.org/master/html/bareos-manual-main-reference.html#x1-400006
I can use **TLS Enable** & **TLS Require** options to enable TLS in client also in inter daemon communication.
I want to disable inter daemon TLS communication but enable TLS in bareos client communicating with s3 server.
Also this TLS config
https://github.com/scality/Droplet/wiki/Configuration-File for droplet file doesn't seems to be working.
Is there any way to configure this???

Comment: Please provide more detail on how you arrived at your conclusion that this *"doesn't seem to be working."*

Comment: I am using droplet.profile configuration which is used by bareos storage daemon. Seems like my droplet is acting like client providing config parameters **access_key** & **secret_key**. The **ssl_ca_list** should contain ca certificate location of server certificate & **should fail if SSL verification fails** but it is accepting any ca certificate.

Comment: Relates to this issue https://github.com/scality/Droplet/issues/160